# Default value for Text Field flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I have a text as a place holder until `onTap()` happen? (onTap is on another page)

```
Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(//Default value goes here
          widget.categoryTitle,//this string comes from another page it changes on every onTap()
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 17.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Right now if no `onTap` happens the `Text` is holding a white blank space, How to replace it with a default/initial value?

Comment: Why not add a ternary to check the value of categoryTitle? If it doesn't exist, put whatever default value you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Ternary operator and assign values as per text

```
       Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(//Default value goes here
              widget.categoryTitle.isEmpty? "Default Text": widget.categoryTitle,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also use shorter version for conditional expressions

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      widget.categoryTitle ?? "Your Default Text Here",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 17.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

expr1 ?? expr2, 
If expr1 (widget.categoryTitle) is non-null, returns its value; otherwise, evaluates and returns the value of expr2 ("Your Default Text Here")